# How force outlook to count unread mails of all folders immediately(without delay)

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013, unread-mail

I have a big problem with **microsoft outlook 2013**,
I've created many **labels** in my **gmail** account and many **filters**.
Filters tell new mails to go to their related labels bypassing **inbox**.
So when i open outlook 2013 it takes a long time to discover and show **unread mails** next every folder.
What is your suggestion to fix that?
Mean when i open outlook just count unread mails of all folders(labels) immediately(without delay) & show them next every folder.
**Or**
How can i create a folder on outlook to show **unread mails** and gather all of them in one folder(label)?

Comment: This is a legit question. So I up-voted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fix. This is how Outlook 2013 works with Gmail. You can work with some settings so that IMAP downloads headers first then messages afterwards. This may help you get unread counts sooner, but not immediately.

Instructions:

- Go to Send / Receive
- Under Download Preferences
- Select Download Headers and Then Full Items

[image]